# Alocamento Banco de Dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server

Tenho algumas dúvidas a respeito do meu banco de dados.

Uso um "banco de dados" MS-SQL, o qual é fornecido pela LocaWeb (não tenho muito claro esse conceito de a LocaWeb me fornecer um "banco" o qual tem dentro dele mais 3 bancos).

Pois bem, ele é dividido em 3 bancos:

```
adautil (o qual uso)
master 
tempdb
```

O master e o tempdb, eu não tenho permissão para editar quaisquer informações.

Executei o comando (o qual acredito que me retorne informações do tamanho do meu banco):

```
EXEC sp_spaceused
```

Achei estranho as informações que obtive:

```
database_name  |   database_size   |    unllocated space
adautil            17.00 MB             1.84 MB
master             176.06 MB            117.34 MB
tempdb             191.56 MB            187.13 MB
```

Não entendi muito o que isso quer dizer, apenas acrescentou algumas dúvidas.

O banco adautil pode encher a qualquer momento? Pois o espaço livre é nem 2.00 MB.

Para que serve o banco master? E o banco tempdb? Eles estão reservando espaço que eu poderia estar utilizando no banco adautil?

Comment: Utilize `sp_helpdb adatina`. O tamanho máximo do banco é o valor `maxsize`. O seu banco de dados cresce de acordo com o uso, até o valor estipulado em maxsize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `master` é o banco de dados onde o SQL Server guarda as suas configurações no nível da instância, similar ao `mysql` no MySQL.

O banco `tempdb`, como o proprio nome sugere, é criado para armazenamento temporário de todos seus bancos, como tabelas temporárias, linhas alteradas em transactions, entre outros

Como o @OnoSendai mencionou, utilize a procedure `sp_helpdb` para verificar o tamanho máximo do seu banco.

Sobre o espaço real que você pode utilizar, consulte seu provedor (no caso a Locaweb). Não sei qual a modalidade de serviço contratado, logo você terá que confirmar diretamente com a Locaweb como seu plano é medido (somente a base de dados, um serviço em nuvem que você pode gerenciar a fundo, etc).

O correto ao meu ver é essas bases não serem consideradas como tamanho máximo do seu plano. Essas bases mantém um tamanho constante, elas não vão fugir muito disso. O `master` guarda as configurações somente e o `tempdb` é reinicializado e limpo quando a instancia no SQL server é reiniciada, zerando seu tamanho.

Mais informações sobre essas bases:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187837.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190768.aspx